# Power BI Format a Measure

Tags: powerbi, format, dax, measure

Hoping to get a help here.

I have plotted a table visualization similar to the below table.

```
| F1 | F2 | F3
|350 | 400| 600
```

where F1 and F2 , F3 are measures and the values changes based on a slicer. But now I need to show the values as percentage of total as below.

```
| F1New   | F2New   |  F3New   |
|350(A%)  |400(B%)  | 600(C%)  |
```

where

```
A = 350/(350+400+600), 
B= 400/(350+400+600),
C = 600/(350+400+600)
```

I've created measures to calculate A , B  and C %

created F1new as this to show the percentage values in bracket.

```
F1New = FORMAT([F1],"#0.00" & "(" & FORMAT([A%],"0.00%") & ")")
```

But I am getting the result as 35000(A%) , 40000(B%) etc.

Tried this as well,

```
F1New = FORMAT([F1]/100,"#0.00" & "(" & FORMAT([A%],"0.00%") & ")")
```

Can we use measure inside Format, I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your parentheses correct? Try F1New = FORMAT ( [F1], "#0.00" ) & "("
    & FORMAT ( [A%], "0.00%" ) & ")"

Comment: Result is still the same even with the parenthesis